# Hot to upload image automaticaly after image preview to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, image-uploading

i got problem in order to upload my image, after sucessfull image preview in jquery to my server. It shows file is not defined in the form.append statement or action.

Tried to fix it on my own but couldn`t find a solution that works.Could you advice me or help me a little bit code is following.

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
        $('#imagePreview').hide();
        $('#imagePreview').fadeIn(650);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
readURL(this);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('formData', file);
$.ajax({
url: 'assets/uploadProfilepic.php',  //Server script to process data
type: 'POST',
data: formData,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
//Ajax events
success: function(html){
    alert(html);
}
});
});
```

The HTML Part

```
<div class="avatar-upload">
        <div class="avatar-edit">
            <input type='file' id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" name="file" />
            <label for="imageUpload"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="avatar-preview">
            <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(http://i.pravatar.cc/500?img=7);">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: file is not defined but it should be or i dont really understand

Please someone could help me a little bit or give a solution.
Thanks and Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file` variable has no defined value in your callback, [so it will use `file` from global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope), which has value `undefined`.
In strict mode, [accessing a variable which has not been declared in local scope raises an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Be sure that just below your call to `readURL(this)` that `file` is assigned to the first file sent by the client (i.e. `this.files[0]`). And to append a file using the `FormData`s:

```
// The first argument ("file") is the POST key for the file
// The file metadata can be retrieved using $_FILES['file']

// The second argument is the file uploaded by the user
// The third argument is the name of the file as perceived by the server
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file, "avatar.png");
```

Keep it mind that to upload files (including avatars), the form should be using the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, so that the browser can send properly the image file.

And implementing a file upload is not all; it is recommended that you validate the file server-side (with PHP, you can use the [mime_content_type](https://php.net/mime_content_type) function, which requires the **fileinfo** extension). Before doing anything, please read [this page on POST file uploads](https://php.net/file-upload).

Comment: Thanks man helped me ive done it another way and much simpler should i check your answer and close tread or write done my method?

Comment: If you find or have to do something that will improve browser compatibility/stability/security, then you can check my answer for reference. But if you're done, you can mark the answer as accepted, as this will help users who have the same problem.